# What to study before PBRT(it's a bit hard)?

Tags: books

I tried reading PBRT but I wasn't able to fully understand the concepts in the book. The following are the two books that I found useful to read before reading PBRT.
[http://www.amazon.com/Ray-Tracing-Ground-Kevin-Suffern/dp/1568812728/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1426597005&sr=1-1&keywords=ray+tracing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812728)
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Tracing-Kaufmann-Computer-Graphics/dp/0122861604/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1426597005&sr=1-3&keywords=ray+tracing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122861604)
Which one will you recommend?

Comment: It's not clear what PBRT is.  In any case, recommendations are generally off-topic here, as they are subjective.  See the [help] for more on what is on-topic for this site.

Comment: PBRT - http://www.pbrt.org/

Comment: Please don't just drop clarifications in the comment field -- edit the question to include all relevant information in the question.  I realize the site design doesn't make this very clear, but comments exist only to help you improve the question, and can disappear at any time.  We expect you to edit your question based on feedback you receive.   You might also want to edit it to make it look prettier (you can list the titles of the books you're asking about and make them a link, rather than having a mess of gobbledygook URL characters).

Comment: If editing, you should also bear in mind the [guidelines for subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).